# Python Pyramid - URL Dispatch and Traversal issue with shash (/)

Tags: python, url, pyramid, traversal

I have a beginner question with URL Dispatch or Traversal. What I am trying to do, is use Mako renderer to render my views. So I have this folder /includes/ where all the html and css and javascript is. Here is my Pyramid main code:

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator

def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.add_static_view('includes', 'includes', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_renderer(".html", "pyramid.mako_templating.renderer_factory")  
    config.add_route('home', '/')
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

And these are my views:

```
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='index.html')
def my_view(request):
    return {'name':'Netherdrake'}

@view_config(name = 'login', renderer='login.html')
def login(request):
    return {'name':'Netherdrake'}
```

The problem is, when I access ip:port/login the site works fine, but when I try ip:port/login/ the css, javascript and images don't work. The reason is, my absolute paths become invalid.

And here is my login.html snippet (which is mako template really) while login without /:

```
 <link href="includes/css/twitter/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="includes/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="includes/css/twitter/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="includes/css/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="includes/js/plugins/modernizr.custom.32549.js"></script>
```

And here it is while Im going for login/ path (site is broken in this case, no css, images, js...):

```
  <link href="includes/css/twitter/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="includes/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="includes/css/twitter/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="includes/css/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="includes/js/plugins/modernizr.custom.32549.js"></script>
```

The login.html is in /includes too.

How can I fix this, and make it work under both paths, with and without slash? I tried traveral and url dispatch, and problem is same in both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your hrefs should begin with an initial slash.